Representation theory of $\mathrm{GL_n}(\mathbb{F}_q)$
I am interested in learning about the classification of irreducible representations of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ as done by Green. One standard reference (besides Green's original work) is MacDonald's book (Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials). MacDonald's book does discuss this topic (Chapter V), but it relies heavily on preceding chapters and notations. I'm wondering if there are any other references that directly explain Green's original paper, providing a more direct pathway to understanding his work.

What is your background?  If you don't yet understand the case of $\text{GL}_2$, I recommend starting by reading Piatetski-Shapiro's little book "Complex Representations of GL(2,K) for Finite Fields K".

Dear @AndyPutman: Thanks for your response. I am familiar with this case (learned it from the same reference)

Do you want to just calculate the character table (which is what Green does), or do you want to actually know how to construct the representations, etc.?

Dear @AndyPutman: Just the character theory. If I understand it correctly, one needs Deligne-Lusztig theory in order to construct the representations. I wonder if this is true.

Yes, you really do need Deligne-Lusztig theory to construct the representations. But the characters, as found by Sandy Green, are much easier to understand. One thing you might want to look at is Zelevinski's "Representations of finite classical groups" (SLNM0869), which provides a wider context for what's going on. Part of the reason, in the case of the general linear groups, why Sandy Green's method works, if I've understood it right, is that there are no cuspidal unipotents, if you'll pardon the long sentence.

(Sorry, I meant Zelevinsky)

MacDonald is the only book I know that does just the character table.  I haven't looked at it in a long time, but I remember that it was pretty readable once you figured out its notation.  I also second Zelevinski.

The following thesis gives a walkthrough of Green's results and has many worked examples: https://researchspace.ukzn.ac.za/server/api/core/bitstreams/f1a4ee61-e892-4a1f-9f15-f4bc9d64760d/content
